# Wait a specific amount of time but not disturb any other function of the application

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

In my game I'm going to implement a function that changes the value of a variable linearly for 5 seconds from 100 to 0. The function has to be launched by the player touching a button.

First, I wanted to do it just by a `for` loop with `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep()` and the value decrementation inside it:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    decrementBatteryLevel();
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I quickly found out that this will cause my entire game to stop for 5 seconds, which is not what I want.
So the first thing I actually tried was creating a thread running the `for` loop:

```
private Thread useBattery = new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        decrementBatteryLevel();
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

And calling it when necessary:

```
useBattery.start();
```

This worked, but only for the first launch. The second launch of the `useBattery` Thread resulted throwing `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` by the game.

I understood that I can't start a thread that is already alive, so I tried doing this:

```
if (useBattery.isAlive()) {
    useBattery.interrupt();
}
useBattery.start();
```

But I ended up with `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` being thrown again. /* Is a Thread a single-use product...? */

The final thing I tried and that actually worked was creating a new Thread every time I needed. So here's what I currently have:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        decrementBatteryLevel();
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

The result of that is satisfying, but I'm afraid that doing so, I quickly fill up RAM with unnecessary, "used up" Threads. Is there any way to do it better?

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ExecutorService` to launch tasks.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

You can then `submit` your `Runnable` or `Callable` to get a hold of a corresponding `Future`.

```
final Future<?> submittedResult = executorService.submit(() -> { /* Your code */ });
```

When launching a new task instance, simply `cancel` and `submit`

```
submittedResult.cancel(true);
executorService.submit(() -> { /* Your code */ });
```

I think you can expand my answer for your specific usecase.
Also, see https://techblog.bozho.net/interrupting-executor-tasks/